# SVG clip-path for masking element: issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have this simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {text-align: center;}
            #dv {
                background-color: red;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                clip-path: url(#mask);
                -webkit-clip-path: url('#mask'); 
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .hidden {width: 0; height: 0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dv"></div>
        <div class="hidden">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="mask">
                         <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="100"/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
                </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I remove the "margin: 0 auto" I can see the masked div.
How can I achieve both margin and mask to work properly in chrome?
(In firefox ot works fine)

Comment: A fiddle to test this: http://jsfiddle.net/8zfW3/1/ clip is actually applied (you can see it, if you resize chrome to a smaller window size).

Comment: @easwee: it works because the size of the window is less than the div, so it is not possible to align the div to center, the div is positioned at left:0, so it is the same as removing margin

Comment: yes - I was just exposing that the mask is infact rendered in chrome - tried a few workarounds in css and also on svg, but none solves the issue. Possible chrome bug (actually latest Opera shows same behaviour so must be webkit related)?

Comment: Opera and Chrome both use Blink, not webkit. In any case, please report Blink-specific bugs to http://crbug.com, thanks :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373358?

Comment: There are still some serious issues with `clip-path` in Chrome, I've got a page that randomly applies the clip or not depending on the position of the elements it's applied to, and even depending on other elements in the page!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the circle keyword instead, if that's what you need:

```
   -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 50% 50%);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zfW3/20/).